# Javascript Hoisting/Scope

Tags: javascript, scope, scoping, hoisting

I'm learning Javascript at the minute and have a question about hoisting/scoping - perhaps I'm missing something.

If I define a global variable, I cant reference that variable's value inside a function because its out of scope?

```
var x = "hello";
function temp(){
     console.log(x);
}
```

turns out to be

```
var x = "hello";
function temp(){
    var x;
    console.log(x);
}
```

which both outputs undefined. What are the points of global variables or how do you use them inside a function? - As I said what am i missing here! :)

Also hoisting works on functions? But NOT on anonymous functions? Correct?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: *"Also hoisting works on functions? But NOT on anonymous functions? Correct?"* No. But there is a difference between function *declarations* and function *expressions*. Also, the first example will output `"hello"`, it's not equivalent to the second example.

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables

Comment: link to a very good examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/2851947

Answer (score 1):

Hoisting only applies to local variables (those declared with `var` in the current scope). Since there's no `var` in `temp()`, there's no hoisting.

Here `x` will be hoisted:

```
var x = "hello";
function temp(){
    console.log(x); // undefined
    var x = 55
}
temp()
```

because this is interpreted as:

```
var x = "hello";
function temp(){
    var x /* = undefined */
    console.log(x);
    x = 55
}
temp()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any variable that is defined in your scope or higher.  If that same variable name is redeclared within your scope, then that becomes a new variable definition that overrides the other one.

So, with this example:

```
var x = "hello";
function temp(){
     console.log(x);   // outputs "hello" when temp() is called
}
```

`x` is defined at a higher scope than the function so it can be used inside the function.

---

In this example:

```
var x = "hello";
function temp(){
    var x;
    console.log(x);   // outputs "undefined" when temp() is called
                      // because local var x has not been assigned a value
}
```

You've defined a new variable `x` which is a local variable inside the function and it's value will be `undefined` until you assign it something.

---

The term "hoisting" means that a variable defined anywhere within a scope (e.g. within a function) behaves as if it was defined at the very beginning of the function no matter where the declaration actually appears.

So, because of hoisting, this example:

```
var x = 10;
function temp() {
    x = 3;
    y = 4;
    var x;
    console.log(x);
}
```

behaves like this and all references to `x` within the function are to the local version of `x`:

```
var x = 10;
function temp() {
    var x;
    x = 3;
    y = 4;
    console.log(x);
}
```